# How can i post combined variable and xml data using jquery ajax for webservice

Tags: jquery, ajax, xml, web-services

I am new in ajax, xml and web service.
    I want to post http request to call webservice with some variable values and xml data with following format:

```
x=sender&b=receiver&xmlinput=<request><data1>100</data1><data2>200</data2></request>
```

Here is my ajax code:

```
//These are the parameters      
var a = 'sender';       
var b = 'receiver';
var xmlinput = '<request><data1>$('#inputData1').val()</data1><data2>$('#inputData2').val()</data2>';       
$.ajax({
    url: 'webService.php',
    type: "POST",   
    async: true,
    data:  "a&b&xml" , 
    dataType: 'xml',
    contentType: "text/xml",
    success: function(xmlData){             

    },                      
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
       console.log(textStatus, errorThrown);
    }
});
```

Please help me to do that.Thanks.

Comment: Put the GET part at the end of the URL and data should be the XML input.

Comment: Check how string concatenation works in JS and use the comment above.

Comment: Thanks @Brainfeeder  you mean this `url: 'webService.php/GET'` ? and also if data ` data:  "xml"` instead of  `data:  "a&b&xml"` then how about other variables `a` and `b`.Thanks

Comment: @user5005768 Exactly :)

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of things you need to look into. In JavaScript use `+` operator for concatenating strings and`contentType: "text/xml"` means that JavaScript expects the `data` value in XML format.
**Note : Unlike in PHP, using variable name in single quoted string, doesn't get processed by javascript. It's treated as a simple string.**

```
var a = 'sender';       
var b = 'receiver';
var xmlinput = '<request><data1>' + $('#inputData1').val() + '</data1><data2>' + $('#inputData2').val() + '</data2>';       
$.ajax({
    url: 'webService.php' ,
    type: "GET",   
    async: true,
    data: {
        xml : xmlinput,
        a: a,
        b: b
    }, 
    dataType: 'xml',
    contentType: "text/xml",
    success: function(xmlData){             

    },                      
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
       console.log(textStatus, errorThrown);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks @Rejith R Krishnan.Is there any way to see or print the final formatted data  `x=sender&b=receiver&xmlinput=<request><data1>100</data1><data2>200</data2></request>` before sending to webservice.This would help to get aware of the correct format.thanks

Comment: @user5005768 : In that case make it `type: "POST"` to `type: "GET"`

Comment: hello @Rejith R Krishnan.will this  code `x=' + a + '&b=' + b` or it will be this `a=' + a + '&b=' + b`. also why you don't send the data part.will this data part automatically concatenate by ajax? thanks

Comment: @user5005768 : I made an update. There was a mistake. With the new code you'll get something like the following. `webService.php?xml=%3Crequest%3E%3Cdata1%3E%23inputData1%3C%2Fdata1%3E%3Cdata2%3E%23inputData2%3C%2Fdata2%3E&a=sender&b=reciever`, which is the url encoded value of your xml and other data,